# how to Install Local Node_Modules in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, ecmascript-6, docker-compose

I have created few local libraries (which can't be publish to npm registry) I can install them locally by npm i ../{PACKAGE_PATH}
but it's not working with docker.

How to install these packeges with dockerfile.

Comment: How do you install them in your local development environment?

Comment: npm i {PATH_OF_MY_LOCAL_PACKAGE}

Comment: Try `COPY {PATH_OF_MY_LOCAL_PACKAGE} {PATH_OF_MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_APPLICATION}`, then `RUN npm install {PATH_OF_MY_DOCKER_IMAGE_APPLICATION}/{PATH_OF_MY_LOCAL_PACKAGE}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use docker volume and mount a directory in which your packages are hold. Having that you could simply see and use the package inside the container.